# Undefined constant "OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT"

Tags: symfony4

[critical] Error thrown while running command "make:entity Gabarit". Message: "Undefined constant "OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT""
[critical] Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT"

In Driver.php line 31:

Undefined constant "OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT"

Je voudrais de l'aide pour ce problème.